# Swift - remove namespaces from XML string

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, swift, namespaces

I have a SOAP reply which have namespaces, like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:doLoginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://mobile.ws.legal.org/"><result>true</result></ns2:doLoginResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to remove xml/envelope/body tags and remove "ns2" namespace from a remaining part?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  But what's your real question?

Comment: You should have put that as answer. Just "Yes"  - lol

Answer (score 0):

Anticipating your intended question: you can use a regex to remove that blurb.

```
let string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><S:Body><ns2:doLoginResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://mobile.ws.legal.org/\"><result>true</result></ns2:doLoginResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>here's the dish"
var error:NSError?
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern:"<\\?xml version.*</S:Envelope>", options:.CaseInsensitive, error:&error)!
let modifiedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string,     options:  NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(string)), withTemplate:"")
println(modifiedString)
```